# Get-AzureStorageAccount now throws after Azure SDK 2.8 upgrade when a storage account is "Creating"

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-powershell, azure-sdk-.net

Get-AzureStorageAccount return all storage accounts, including ones that were in the state of Creating for Azure SDK 2.8

It now throws with

> Get-AzureStorageAccount : ResourceNotFound: The storage account
>   'MyStorage' was not found.